# How can I add these custom cells to a TableView?

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms, how can I achieve a layout like this one?

[image]

I'm talking about the textual hints on grey background:

> Turn on Personal Hotspot to share ...

All I can add to a `ListView` or `TableView` are standard `ViewCells`, and they all get rendered with separators and white background.

If this layout isn't possible by using `TableView` or `ListView`, how can I render a `ViewCell` (like the Wi-Fi Password one in the sample image) in a standard `StackLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

Even though there's no out-of-the-box `ViewCell` for the TableView to do that, you can certainly roll out your own implementation. There obviously is a TextCell but it doesn't let you specify the font size and other stuff.

You could do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="DemoTableView.TablePage" Title="TableView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <TableView Intent="Settings">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection>
                    <SwitchCell Text="Personal Hotspot" />
                    <ViewCell> <!-- Simple text -->
                        <Label Text="Turn on personal hotspot..." FontSize="Small" ForegroundColor="Gray" />
                    </ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell> <!-- More complex cell -->
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal>
                            <Image Source="someicon" />
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="TO CONNECT USING WIFI" FontSize="Large"/>
                                <Label Text="Something more" FontSize="Small" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is just a quick example written in hurry but you get the idea. You can also programmatically define your own cells by inheriting from the `ViewCell` class and show them in the TableView.

[Here's more](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/#Custom_Cells) about custom cells on the official documentation.

---

**Edit:** As per your comment, we need to dig a bit into the platform specific code to disable selection on the text-only cells. You should create a custom ViewCell implementation with the following custom renderer for iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportCell(typeof(YourCell), typeof(YourCellRenderer))]
namespace YourProject.iOS
{
    public class YourCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (Cell item, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell (item, tv);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but using a ViewCell has two downsides: a) I still get a hover effect on tapping the cell, b) The separator from the SwitchCell above shrinks slightly, as it normally would if there are more options below. Any idea on how to overcome these problems?

Comment: @Physikbuddha Oh right, didn't think of that. I updated my answer. Not quite sure about b though.